# How to display popular/trending Youtube videos from the front page on Android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to build an android youtube app and to start it off, I would like the main page to display popular videos that are featured on youtube's homepage.

How can I get the necessary info to implement it on my listview? I was digging around the google developers website but could not find any lead as to how to request such information.
any help would be appreciated!
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `chart` filter as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters) with the value `mostPopular`. See the sample code on that link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have fetched the top trending videos and play them on the app iteself .
First you need to sign in via google , this can be done in simple code structure given below.

```
private static GoogleAccountCredential credential;
public static final String[] SCOPES = {Scopes.PROFILE, 
YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE};
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "";
private HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
private JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
public static final String APP_NAME = "Your Google Project Name";

credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
Arrays.asList(Auth.SCOPES));
            credential.setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
            scopes = 
Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");

credential.setSelectedAccountName(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME);
```

After selecting account , you can load videos into your app - Call loadVideos().

```
    public void loadVideos() 
{  
     if (PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME == null)
        {
        System.out.println("First need to authorize app");
        return;
        }


     new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<VideoData>>()

        {
            @Override
            protected List<VideoData> doInBackground (Void...voids){

                credential.setSelectedAccountName(name);

                YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(transport, 
                    jsonFactory,
                    credential).setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
                    .build();

            try {


                 videos = new ArrayList<VideoData>();


                VideoListResponse videoListResponse = youtube.videos().
                        list("snippet,statistics")
                       .setChart("mostPopular")
                       .setMaxResults((long)20)
                       .setRegionCode("IN").
                        execute();

                List<Video> videoList = videoListResponse.getItems();
                if (videoList.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Can't find a video with ID: ");
                    return null;
                }

                for (Video video : videoListResponse.getItems()) {

                    VideoData videoData = new VideoData();
                    videoData.setVideo(video);
                    videos.add(videoData);

                }
                System.out.println(videoList.size());


                return videos;

            } catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException 
              availabilityException) {

            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException 
              userRecoverableException) {
                startActivityForResult(
                        userRecoverableException.getIntent(),
                        REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Utils.logAndShow(getActivity(), Constants.APP_NAME, e);
            }
            return null;
        }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute (List < VideoData > videos) {


            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (videos == null) {
                return;
            }



        }

        }

        .execute((Void)
                null);

}
```

VideoClass contains- getter setter for getting data.

```
public class VideoData {
private Video mVideo;

public Video getVideo() {
    return mVideo;
}

public void setVideo(Video video) {
    mVideo = video;
}

public String getYouTubeId() {
    return mVideo.getId();
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mVideo.getSnippet().getTitle();
}

public String getLikes(){
    return   String.valueOf(mVideo.getStatistics().getLikeCount());
}
public  String getViewCount(){
    return mVideo.getStatistics().getViewCount().toString();
}

public VideoSnippet addTags(Collection<? extends String> tags) {
    VideoSnippet mSnippet = mVideo.getSnippet();
    List<String> mTags = mSnippet.getTags();
    if (mTags == null) {
        mTags = new ArrayList<String>(2);
    }
    mTags.addAll(tags);
    return mSnippet;
}

public String getThumbUri() {
    return mVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getHigh().getUrl();
}

public String getWatchUri() {
    return "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + getYouTubeId();
}
}
```

You can manipulate VideoList by applying filter to Videoresponse list.
Filters can be find at [Youtube Api v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/)

For your information below Code Refer to link https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3
. App package iteself forms the link.

```
new YouTube.Builder(transport, 
                jsonFactory,
                credential).setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
                .build();
```

Let me know if you have doubts or need working prototype.